# Lucene 6.1 Custom Tokenizer and Analyzer

Tags: java, lucene, tokenize

I'm asking for some help with Lucene 6.1 API.

I tried to extend Lucene's `Tokenizer` and `Analyzer`, but I don't understand all guides. In all tutorials, User's `Tokenizer` overrides the increment. In constructor they have `Reader` class and in User's `Analyzer` class they override `createComponents` method. But in Lucene it has only 1 String argument, so how can I add Reader to my `Analyzer`?

My code:

```
public class ChemTokenizer extends Tokenizer{
    protected CharTermAttribute charTermAttribute = addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
    protected String stringToTokenize;
    protected int position = 0;
    protected List<int[]> chemicals = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
        // Clear anything that is already saved in this.charTermAttribute
        this.charTermAttribute.setEmpty();

        // Get the position of the next symbol
        int nextIndex = -1;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^A-zА-я]");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(stringToTokenize.substring(position));
        nextIndex = m.start();
        // Did we lose chemicals?
        for (int[] pair: chemicals) {
            if (pair[0] < nextIndex && pair[1] > nextIndex) {
                //We are in the chemical name
                if (position == pair[0]) {
                    nextIndex = pair[1];
                }
                else {
                    nextIndex = pair[0];
                }
            }
        }
        // Next separator was found
        if (nextIndex != -1) {
            String nextToken = stringToTokenize.substring(position, nextIndex);
            charTermAttribute.append(nextToken);
            position = nextIndex + 1;
            return true;
        }
        // Last part of text
        else if (position < stringToTokenize.length()) {
            String nextToken = stringToTokenize.substring(position);
            charTermAttribute.append(nextToken);
            position = stringToTokenize.length();
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public ChemTokenizer(Reader reader,List<String> additionalKeywords) {
        int numChars;
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            while ((numChars =
                    reader.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                stringBuilder.append(buffer, 0, numChars);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        stringToTokenize = stringBuilder.toString();
        //Checking for keywords
        //Doesnt work properly if text has chemical synonyms
        for (String keyword: additionalKeywords) {
            int[] tmp = new int[2];
            //Start of keyword
            tmp[0] = stringToTokenize.indexOf(keyword);
            tmp[1] = tmp[0] + keyword.length() - 1;
            chemicals.add(tmp);
        }
    }

    /* Reset the stored position for this object when reset() is called.
     */
    @Override
    public void reset() throws IOException {
        super.reset();
        position = 0;
        chemicals = new ArrayList<>();

    }
}
```

And code for `Analyzer`:

```
public class ChemAnalyzer extends Analyzer{

    List<String> additionalKeywords;
    public ChemAnalyzer(List<String> ad) {
        additionalKeywords = ad;
    }
    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String s, Reader reader) {
        Tokenizer tokenizer = new ChemTokenizer(reader,additionalKeywords);
        TokenStream filter = new LowerCaseFilter(tokenizer);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer, filter);
    }

}
```

The problem is that this code doesn't work with Lucene 6

Comment: what does it mean, it's not working with Lucene 6? Compile error? Bug? Not desired behaviour?

Comment: In lucene 6 createComponents has different description.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found in [github search](https://github.com/yipen9/my_lucene/blob/2341c11790945a3c2a25fb5d1d46b844277859a0/lucene-core/src/main/java/org/apache/lucene/yipeng/analysis/WhitespaceAnalyzer.java), guess you have to create a new tokenizer with out read.

```
@Override
protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName) {
    return new TokenStreamComponents(new WhitespaceTokenizer()); }
```